# Why does Tonellis theorem imply that the order of integration doesn't matter?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal E, \mu)$ and $(Y, \mathcal F, \nu)$ be measure spaces.

In my textbook Tonellis theorem is stated for a non-negative function $f \in \mathcal M(\mathcal E \otimes\mathcal F)^+$ s.t $$\int_{X \times Y} f(x,y) (\mu \otimes\nu)(dx,dy) = \int_X (\int_Y f(x,y) \nu(dy))\mu(dx) \ \ \ (1)$$.

It is then said that by interchanging $x$ and $y$ we have $$\int_{X \times Y} f(x,y) (\mu \otimes\nu)(dx,dy) = \int_Y (\int_X f(x,y) \mu(dx))\nu(dy) \ \ \ (2)$$, However I don't see why $(1)$ imply $(2)$ by interchaning $x$ and $y$.

Can someone clarify this ?

Comment: Apply Tonelli to the measure $\nu\otimes\mu$. (And you really should replace your $\oplus$es by $\otimes$es.)

Comment: But then we integrate over $Y \times X$ ? And $f$ might be undefined on this ?

Comment: Yes we integrate over $Y\times X$, and of course we integrate the function $g$ defined on $Y\times X$ by $g(y,x)=f(x,y)$.

Comment: Can you agree that $\nu \otimes \mu "=" \mu \otimes \nu$?

Comment: But how can we say that the two iterated integrals are equal ? I mean the "base" is different.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom "Can you agree that ν⊗μ"="μ⊗ν?" No, and I see no reason why I should.

Comment: You can replace f(x,y) in the RHS of (1) by g(y,x) if it makes you feel better but this is really an excessive fixation on notational rigor, if you ask me.